# Call any type of solver in Eigen from a SolverBaseClass pointer

Tags: c++, eigen, eigen3

I want to create a class which is able to call any type of Linear Solver from Eigen library. In the constructor I indicate with an enum which type of solver I want to use. I'm defining a class member `solver` of type `Eigen::SparseSolverBase<Eigen::SparseMatrix<double>>` which is the base for all Sparse Solvers in Eigen. Depending on the value of my `solverType` enum I would like `solver` to be that specific type of solver. At the moment my header looks like this.

```
#pragma once

#include <Eigen/SparseCore>
#include<Eigen/SparseCholesky>
#include<Eigen/SparseQR>
#include<Eigen/SparseLU>
#include<Eigen/IterativeLinearSolvers>
#include <iostream>
#include <unsupported/Eigen/SparseExtra>

enum solverType
{
    SimplicialLLT,
    SimplicialLDLT,
    SparseLU,
    ConjugateGradient,
    LeastSquaresConjugateGradient,
    BiCGSTAB
};

class LinearSolver
{

public:
    LinearSolver(Eigen::SparseMatrix<double> &A, Eigen::VectorXd &b, solverType type) : A(A), b(b) {
        switch (type) {
            case 0:
                solver = new Eigen::SimplicialLLT<Eigen::SparseMatrix<double>>();
            case 1:
                solver = new Eigen::SimplicialLDLT<Eigen::SparseMatrix<double>>();
            case 2:
                solver = new Eigen::SparseLU<Eigen::SparseMatrix<double>>();
            case 3:
                solver = new Eigen::ConjugateGradient<Eigen::SparseMatrix<double>>();
            case 4:
                solver = new Eigen::LeastSquaresConjugateGradient<Eigen::SparseMatrix<double>>();
            case 5:
                solver = new Eigen::BiCGSTAB<Eigen::SparseMatrix<double>>();
        }
        solver->compute(A);
    };
    ~LinearSolver() = default;

private:
    Eigen::SparseMatrix<double> A;
    Eigen::VectorXd b;
    Eigen::SparseSolverBase<Eigen::SparseMatrix<double>> *solver;
};
```

Unfortunately it does not compile and raises the following error:

```
error: cannot convert ‘Eigen::SimplicialLLT<Eigen::SparseMatrix<double> >*’ to ‘Eigen::SparseSolverBase<Eigen::SparseMatrix<double> >*’ in assignment
   31 |                 solver = new Eigen::SimplicialLLT<Eigen::SparseMatrix<double>>();
```

I know that direct solvers and indirect solvers do not directly inherit from `Eigen::SparseSolverBase` but it is the only common class for all solvers. Any idea how can I accomplish this?

Comment: You are missing the CRTP bit: `Eigen::SimplicialLLT<Eigen::SparseMatrix<double>>` inherits from `Eigen::SparseSolverBase<Eigen::SimplicialLLT<Eigen::SparseMatrix<double>>>` not from `Eigen::SparseSolverBase<Eigen::SparseMatrix<double>>`.

Comment: Hey thanks. I guess that's the specific case for SimplicialLLT but what if I want to use conjugent gradient for example? It looks to me that CRTP does not allow to define a BaseClass pointer which depending on the enum changes to point to a specific derived class. I had on mind dynamic casting the base pointer to the specific derived indicated by enum in the constructor but Im unable to do it due to CRTP in Eigen

Comment: That's exactly the point: Since the solvers don't share a common base class your dynamic approach will not work. If you can use C++17 you could try `std::variant` or `std::any`. The cleanest and most Eigenish solution would be to choose the solver at compile-time using a template argument.